# UIAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler using global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I'm calling an UIAlertController with 2 textfields(in Obj-C). I've defined global UITextFields that I need to use in the alert because I need to take advantage of the UITextFieldDelegate.

My textfields are defined in the .h file as such.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *nameField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *phoneField;
```

Is there a way to recast the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler block from this:

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *myField) {
        myField.delegate = self;
    }];
```

to something like this... Where I can assign the textfield I defined earlier to use in this block?

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(**nameField**) {
            nameField.delegate = self;
        }];
```

What I'm looking to do is this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == nameField) {
        phoneField.text = @"";
    }

    if (textField == phoneField) {
        nameField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

If one field has text, the other should be blank. It works outside of the alertview without any problems... but inside the block, it will not clear the other field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need to replace the built-in text field with your own?

Comment: Because I need to use one of the delegate methods in a certain way... It won't work as is.

Comment: You can't replace the text field with your own. You need to make the delegate work. Update your question with relevant details about the issue you are having.

Comment: Updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign your global variable as a pointer inside the block

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *aTextField) {
        GLOBAL_VARIABLE = aTextField;//<- pointer
        aTextField.delegate = self;
    }];
```

Then you can properly use your conditionals in the callback.

Note: Replace `GLOBAL_VARIABLE` with whatever your global variable textifleds are

Comment: Thank you so much!